# Mysql variable inside a long query

Tags: mysql, sql

I think to have a problem with variable inside my mysql query on mysql 5.6:

```
SELECT DISTINCT TRIM(TRAILING '.' FROM merge_s.rdata) AS `content`,
            '120' AS ttl,
            `merge_s`.`pri` AS `prio`,
            (SELECT type FROM types WHERE type = @type:='MX') AS `type`,
            (SELECT id FROM soa WHERE CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX((SELECT @rr:='mina.net'),'.',-2),'.')=soa.origin) AS domain_id,
            `merge_s`.`rr` AS `rr`
    FROM (`merge_s` LEFT JOIN `merge_s` `db2` ON
            (((`merge_s`.`rr` = `db2`.`rr`) AND (`merge_s`.`pri` < `db2`.`pri`) and (`merge_s`.`type` = `db2`.`type`))))
    WHERE ((`merge_s`.`status` = '1') OR (`merge_s`.`type` = 'NS') OR (`merge_s`.`type` = 'SOA')) AND
            (isnull(`db2`.`pri`) OR (`merge_s`.`type` = 'MX')) AND
            (merge_s.type=@type AND merge_s.rr=@rr)
```

the query returns correct but without rows. The same query, where i replace by hands the last row (merge_s.type=@type AND merge_s.rr=@rr) with what i aspects in this variable returns the right 2 rows

```
SELECT DISTINCT TRIM(TRAILING '.' FROM merge_s.rdata) AS `content`,
            '120' AS ttl,
            `merge_s`.`pri` AS `prio`,
            (SELECT type FROM types WHERE type = @type:='MX') AS `type`,
            (SELECT id FROM soa WHERE CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX((SELECT @rr:='mina.net'),'.',-2),'.')=soa.origin) AS domain_id,
            `merge_s`.`rr` AS `rr`
    FROM (`merge_s` LEFT JOIN `merge_s` `db2` ON
            (((`merge_s`.`rr` = `db2`.`rr`) AND (`merge_s`.`pri` < `db2`.`pri`) and (`merge_s`.`type` = `db2`.`type`))))
    WHERE ((`merge_s`.`status` = '1') OR (`merge_s`.`type` = 'NS') OR (`merge_s`.`type` = 'SOA')) AND
            (isnull(`db2`.`pri`) OR (`merge_s`.`type` = 'MX')) AND
            (merge_s.type='MX' AND merge_s.rr='mina.net')
```

the 2 rows:

```
content         ttl     prio    type    domain_id   rr  
mail.mina.net   120     50       MX       3         mina.net
mail.tes.net    120     60       MX       3         mina.net
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your query, the variables are being set in subqueries in the `select` clause:

```
SELECT DISTINCT TRIM(TRAILING '.' FROM merge_s.rdata) AS `content`,
       '120' AS ttl, `merge_s`.`pri` AS `prio`,
        (SELECT type FROM types WHERE type = @type:='MX') AS `type`,
        (SELECT id
         FROM soa
         WHERE CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX((SELECT @rr:='mina.net'),'.',-2),'.')=soa.origin
        ) AS domain_id,
        `merge_s`.`rr` AS `rr`
FROM `merge_s` LEFT JOIN
     `merge_s` `db2`
      ON(((`merge_s`.`rr` = `db2`.`rr`) AND (`merge_s`.`pri` < `db2`.`pri`) and (`merge_s`.`type` = `db2`.`type`))))
WHERE ((`merge_s`.`status` = '1') OR (`merge_s`.`type` = 'NS') OR (`merge_s`.`type` = 'SOA')) AND
      (isnull(`db2`.`pri`) OR (`merge_s`.`type` = 'MX')) AND
      (merge_s.type=@type AND merge_s.rr=@rr);
```

What you have discovered is that a lot of processing happens in the SQL statement *before* such clauses are executed.  In general, the `from` clause is the first clause executed and the `select` is one of the last.  I always put variable declarations in the main `from` clause using a `cross join`.  This version should work:

```
SELECT DISTINCT TRIM(TRAILING '.' FROM merge_s.rdata) AS `content`,
       '120' AS ttl, `merge_s`.`pri` AS `prio`,
        (SELECT type FROM types WHERE type = @type) AS `type`,
        (SELECT id
         FROM soa
         WHERE CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX( @rr,'.',-2),'.')=soa.origin
        ) AS domain_id,
        `merge_s`.`rr` AS `rr`
FROM `merge_s` LEFT JOIN
     `merge_s` `db2`
      ON(((`merge_s`.`rr` = `db2`.`rr`) AND (`merge_s`.`pri` < `db2`.`pri`) and
          (`merge_s`.`type` = `db2`.`type`)))) cross join
      (select @type:='MX', @rr:='mina.net') const
WHERE ((`merge_s`.`status` = '1') OR (`merge_s`.`type` = 'NS') OR (`merge_s`.`type` = 'SOA')) AND
      (isnull(`db2`.`pri`) OR (`merge_s`.`type` = 'MX')) AND
      (merge_s.type=@type AND merge_s.rr=@rr);
```

Comment: Delete the last ) before cross join to fix the syntax error. I can't edit that alone because stackoverflow wants that i fix at least 7 char but here it's only 1 char. In mysql 5.5 the first query posted was working, but in 5.6 no more. I don't know why. Your solution, it's a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can have it on top of SELECT

```
SET @rr:='mina.net';

SELECT DISTINCT TRIM(TRAILING '.' FROM merge_s.rdata) AS `content`,
                '120' AS ttl,
                `merge_s`.`pri` AS `prio`,
                (SELECT type FROM types WHERE type = @type:='MX') AS `type`,
                (SELECT id FROM soa WHERE CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX((SELECT @rr:='mina.net'),'.',-2),'.')=soa.origin) AS domain_id,
                `merge_s`.`rr` AS `rr`
        FROM (`merge_s` LEFT JOIN `merge_s` `db2` ON
                (((`merge_s`.`rr` = `db2`.`rr`) AND (`merge_s`.`pri` < `db2`.`pri`) and (`merge_s`.`type` = `db2`.`type`))))
        WHERE ((`merge_s`.`status` = '1') OR (`merge_s`.`type` = 'NS') OR (`merge_s`.`type` = 'SOA')) AND
                (isnull(`db2`.`pri`) OR (`merge_s`.`type` = 'MX')) AND
                (merge_s.type=@type AND merge_s.rr=@rr)
```